# Why nmap is giving me different results than Python when scanning ports?

Tags: python, scapy, nmap

I'm pentester-student and I very much like to complement tasks
with Python version of it.

I've got a vulnerable box with IP 192.168.41.2 and port scanning with
nmap resulted in:

```
nmap -T4 -p- 192.168.41.2
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-27 15:13 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.41.2
Host is up (0.00024s latency).
All 65535 scanned ports on 192.168.41.2 are closed
MAC Address: 00:50:56:EA:44:EB (VMware)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.72 seconds
```

Telling me there are no open ports. Then I check the results with Python script:

```
from scapy.all import *
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('ip')
args = parser.parse_args()
ip = args.ip

ports = [i for i in range(65535)]

def synScan(host):
    resp, _ = sr(IP(dst=host)/TCP(sport=5555, dport=ports, flags='S'), timeout=2, verbose=0)
    print(f'Open ports on {host}:\n')
    for s, r in resp:
        if s[TCP].dport == r[TCP].sport:
            print(f'TCP Port {s[TCP].dport} is open.')


synScan(ip)
```

script executed by running `python3 port_scanner.py 192.168.41.2` which resulted in:

```
Open ports on host 192.168.41.2:
TCP Port 0 is open.
TCP Port 1 is open.
TCP Port 2 is open.
TCP Port 3 is open.
TCP Port 4 is open.
TCP Port 5 is open.
TCP Port 6 is open.
TCP Port 7 is open.
TCP Port 8 is open.
TCP Port 9 is open.
TCP Port 10 is open.
TCP Port 11 is open.
TCP Port 12 is open.
TCP Port 13 is open.
TCP Port 14 is open.
TCP Port 15 is open.
TCP Port 16 is open.
TCP Port 17 is open.
TCP Port 18 is open.
TCP Port 19 is open.
TCP Port 20 is open.
TCP Port 21 is open.
TCP Port 22 is open.
TCP Port 23 is open.
TCP Port 24 is open.
...
...
```

My question is which scan I should trust more ? Nmap is very popular network scanner and scapy is pretty popular too but here you see the results.

Comment: Have you run both against a machine you have access to and see what ports are actually open?  I would probably trust the one that is actually correct.

Comment: It's a vuln box on my network. And no logins and I can't run `ifconfig`. No nothing.

Comment: So run it against a machine on which you can run ifconfig?  scanme.insecure.org would be a candidate if you really don't have one locally.

Comment: Just use any random website to check..```nmap -6 -sV www.gcm-nieland.de``` has port ```80,443``` open as expected, just check if both tools yield the same. Btw, look at the nice golden retriever on the website ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scapy script concludes that the port is open if you receive an answer to a `SYN` packet.  This is wrong. For example, if the answer is an `RST` packet, the port is closed.  This script rather tells if the port is filtered.

So if you want to use scapy you'll also have to check that the answer packet has the `SYN` packet also set.

Comment: Further filtering is needed. Understood. I'll adjust the script.